# Which state should I convert to absorption in an Absorbing Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, graph-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I am interested in the properties of a particle moving in a grid of cells.

I have a grid of cells modeled as a weighted undirected graph, such that every cell has eight neighbors. Some of the cells in the grid are labeled as termination cells such that if a particle is in that cell it is stuck/terminated.

I am then creating an Absorbing Markov Chain from this graph with the non-termination cells being transient states (t) and the termination cells absorption states (r).

What I am initially interested in is the expected time to termination for starting that random process from each cell.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) I make the matrix

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}Q & R\\ 0 & I_r\end{pmatrix}$$

where $Q$ is a t-by-t matrix, $R$ is a nonzero t-by-r matrix, $0$ is an r-by-t zero matrix, and $I_r$ is the r-by-r identity matrix. Thus, $Q$ describes the probability of transitioning from some transient state to another while $R$ describes the probability of transitioning from some transient state to some absorbing state.

I create the transition probabilities based on the weights in the graph. Since this is a large grid (at least 200x200) I have a P matrix around 40000x40000, thus to calculate the expected time to termination I solve $$(I - Q)x = 1$$
for $x$ where $1$ is a vector of all ones.
Which is computationally faster than $$x = (I-Q)^{-1}1$$

What I would like to know is if I were to make on of the transient states an absorption state, which one should I pick to reduce the mean of the expected time to termination vector $x$? $$\frac{1}{t}\sum x$$

I am assuming this is possible given the graph and $x$ but maybe it is not?

Comment: Is your graph a ball ? Could you brute force this ?

Comment: I have a toy version of the problem with a 30x30 grid that I can brute force (200x200 gives too many states). I only use it for testing all of the failed things I have tried so far. It is not a ball but I do wrap the two edges of the grid together so the problem is technically for a cylinder. Also the top and bottom rings of the cylinder are the initial absorption states